# Set properties of bean inside form from jsp in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have Bean A{ B b;} which encapsulates instance of Bean B.
I have property name which i want to set name property of Bean B. Is there any way i can do it Spring. Currently i am using AbstractCommandController.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind a property of the nested object to the form field, you can do it using `.` in `path` attribute:

```
<form:form ...>
    <form:input path = "b.name" />
</form:form>
```